# Открытие qml окна с С++

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcreator

Всем привет. Никак не могу открыть обычное qml окно с стороны С++. Как бы вы реализовали данную функцию?

У меня вот такое решение:

```
view->setSource(QUrl::fromLocalFile(QApplication::applicationDirPath() + "EQDriveUpdateWindow.qml"));
view->show();
```

Но в итоге открывается и моё созданное окно и просто пустое окно. Как исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Вангую - вы использовали QQuickView для отображения QML, но забыли заменить объявление окна на альтернативный корневой элемент.

main.cpp

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QQuickView>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQuickView view;
    view.setSource(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));
    view.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 100
        width: 100
        text: "123"
    }
}
```

При таком раскладе вы бы получили исчерпывающее предупреждение в консоли...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исправить достаточно просто - нужно заменить корневой элемент Window на Item с привязкой ширины и высоты к родителю

```
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    Button {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        height: 100
        width: 100
        text: "123"
    }
    onParentChanged: {
        width=Qt.binding(()=>parent.width);
        height=Qt.binding(()=>parent.height);
    }
}
```